# Android: Widget doesn't save CountDown variable

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I'm making an Android widget which launches a CountDown when I click on a button (signaled by the intent *TAG_WAIT2_CLICK*).
I'd like the button not to launch a new CountDown until the current CountDown finishes.
The problem is that each time I click on the button, the variable *countDown* remains null and therefore *launch_timer* gets true and therefore a new CountDown is launched.
Any idea why?

```
public class AlphaProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private CountDown countDown;
    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
    {
        boolean launch_timer;

        if (paramIntent.getAction().equals(TAG_WAIT2_CLICK)) {
            if (countDown == null) launch_timer = true;
            else if (!countDown.isTicking()) launch_timer = true;
            else launch_timer = false;

            if (launch_timer) {
                String str = paramIntent.getAction();
                RemoteViews localRemoteViews = buildUpdate(paramContext, str);
                ComponentName localComponentName = new ComponentName(paramContext, AlphaProvider.class);
                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext).updateAppWidget(localComponentName, localRemoteViews);

                countDown = new CountDown(6000, 1000, rview, paramContext, R.id.progressBar_Wait2, R.id.textViewWait2);
                countDown.start();                    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            super.onReceive(paramContext, paramIntent);
        }
    }
}    

public class CountDown extends CountDownTimer {
    private RemoteViews views;
    private Context paramContext;
    private int secondsMax;
    private int ProgressBarId;
    private int TextViewId;
    private boolean isTicking;

    public CountDown(long millisInFuture, int countDownInterval, RemoteViews views, Context paramContext, int ProgressBarId, int TextViewId) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        this.views = views;
        this.paramContext = paramContext;
        this.secondsMax = (int) (millisInFuture / 1000);
        this.ProgressBarId = ProgressBarId;
        this.TextViewId = TextViewId;
        this.isTicking = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        int secondsLeft = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        views.setProgressBar(ProgressBarId,this.secondsMax,secondsLeft,false);
        if (secondsLeft<=0)
        {
            isTicking = false;
        } else {
            isTicking = true;
        }

        ComponentName localComponentName = new ComponentName(paramContext, AlphaProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext).updateAppWidget(localComponentName, views);
    }

    public boolean isTicking() { return isTicking; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you return from `onReceive()`, any manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`, such as your `AppWidgetProvider`, is discarded and will be garbage-collected. In addition, if nothing else is keeping your process around (e.g., a foreground service), your process will be terminated fairly soon, to free up system RAM for other apps.

Comment: This makes complete sense. I had not realized the garbage-collector is destroying my object. That said, I really can't see how I can "save" the fact that the CountDown is still counting.

Comment: @rockline: On the whole, I would recommend that you work on some other project. You will soon start running into Android restrictions that are designed to help with battery life, privacy/security, and other things. However, if you insist on continuing on this, you will need to have a foreground service (to keep your process alive), plus have your countdown logic be managed by something outside the scope of a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` (e.g., a Hilt-supplied singleton).

Comment: Thank you, I'll investigate this path.